# Why do I get an Error when I try to rename a table after FROM?

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

When I simply try to retrieve all of the rows in my table `EMPLOYEE` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE AS emp;
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended 
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action: 
Error at Line: 14 Column: 11
```

If I remove the `AS emp` it works just perfectly fine, but I want to rename my table here. Am I missing something totally obvious?

Comment: Should be fine. But some dbms products (e.g. Oracle) don't like the `AS` keyword there. Try without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that is a problem with your database engine. From the error i gather you are using Oracle. Oracle alias for tables is: `table_name alias_name` (https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/alias.php)

So change the query to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE emp;
```