# PL SQL : Oracle database error 907: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute below PL SQL query

```
select m.*, n.region_building_count from 
(SELECT
  a.BUILDING_ID as "Building Id",
  d.Building_name as "Building Name",
  d.ADDRESS as "Building Address",
  d.REGION as "Region",
  d.Country as "Country",
  d.State as "State",
  d.City as "City"
FROM Company a, LOCATION d
where 1=1
and a.Building_ID like 'BLD-%') m
left JOIN
(select count(building_id) region_building_count, region from LOCATION l where l.Building_ID like 'BLD-%' group by region) n
on m.region = n.region
```

But keep getting error like

```
Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "M"."REGION": invalid identifier
```

Any idea what I am missing

Comment: Commas in the `FROM` clause?  `LEFT JOIN` after `WHERE`?  Your query is filled with errors.  Please review the basic syntax of queries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489364/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-i-try-to-rename-a-table-after-from

Comment: Also there's no PL/SQL in the question.

Comment: Where clause is part of subquery. What am I missing? Can you please point out the mistakes.

Comment: I removed "as" from the query now getting. Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "M"."REGION": invalid identifier